# call aspx page from my java web application

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, jsp, reporting-services

Is there a way to call my aspx page from my java web application? I got a reportviewer from my aspx and I need to show it on my web application (java).

so this is the example [i want to show the aspx page on the "sample report panel"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEV2Y.png)

Comment: what have you tried so far?  I guess that `asp` is just a web service like any other

Comment: The aspx is actually a web page that has a report viewer connected to a ssrs report that I made.. And I want to call that page to my java web page. Is it possible?

Comment: Not enough info. Do you mean you have a Java web app and you want the server to fetch html generated by your ASPX application?

Comment: so you can do it the same way as calling other web services from your java web application - unless you post something that you have tried it is hard to understand where it the web application you are trying to do it (servlet, jsp, ajax etc)

Comment: OK so assuming your ASPX application is available publicly or on the same network, you can make an http call to it and you could embed the html you receive into the response stream, See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests. I don't think it's necessarily a great idea to do that though,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad idea. You shouldn't be mixing output from a C# application into your Java application, though it's possible, in the sense that you could make an http request from the Java app to the the ASPX app, take the HTML you get back and embed it. However the ASPX app probably sends back a full HTML page, so you'd somehow need to strip out the report from the HTML, a hack of major proportions. You should rewrite the report in Java.